# Read query parameter from a Twilio post request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I have a simple web application using twilio and sinatra.

Here it is:

```
# Responds to POSTs to http://yourapp.com/call
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

post '/call' do
    to = params[:To]
    puts to
    "<Response><Say>Congratulations! You got through</Say></Response>"
end
```

The call gets through, but the "to" field that [twilio sends in its request](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) as a query parameter is not read. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the params hash with a stringified key. e.g.

```
to = params['To']
```

In Rails using a symbol would work because Rails extends the Rack params hash to have indifferent access. So in Rails, the following is true.

```
params['To'] == params[:To]
```

This can cause confusion when using other Rack frameworks.

Hope this helps.

S